# Norton equivalent resistance of zero?

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, resistance, norton

I am trying to analyze this circuit using norton.

[image]

Load (20 Ω) is connected between A and B.

I have removed the load and calculated the norton current to be -2A.

Now I try to calculate the norton resistance. Without the load, I short circuit the voltage source and remove the current source.

I end with this!!!

[image]

what??? the circuit is interrupted. There is no more A or B, or \$ V_{AB} = 0 \$

Is the norton resistance 0 or infinity?

How do I do that? How do I interpret that?

Comment: what's the resistance between A and B

Comment: You want the Norton equivalent that's driving R5, or you want the Norton equivalent if you connected some new load between A and B?

Comment: I want to norton if I connect something between A and B. I have fixed that info on the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barry's answer would be correct if you were treating \$R_5\$ as the load because in that case, you'd have to remove it from the circuit. According to what you are saying, the load is something else you would attach to the existing circuit (which includes \$R_5\$).

Now, if \$R_5\$ is still part of the circuit after you remove the load, when you deactivate the sources, as you did, the resistance at the A-B points (the Norton resistance) is \$=R_5\$: It's neither 0 nor \$\infty\$ in this case. This is the case because the rest of the circuit is disconnected from \$R_5\$ and your Ohmmeter would measure across \$R_5\$ only.

Another way to look at it is, if you connected a test source between those terminals (A-B), the current would only flow through \$R_5\$, that is its only path (current wouldn't flow through the open).

If \$R_5\$ is the load and you needed to remove it to find the Norton equivalent, in that case, the resistance looking into there would very large, \$\to \infty\$.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit for calculating the Norton resistance is correct.  The resistance between A and B is infinite since R4 is not connected to anything.  This actually makes perfect sense since your circuit, as far as points A and B is concerned,is just an ideal constant current source of 2 amps. The resistance of a constant current source is infinite. Any load connected between A and B is going to see only the constant current source.  The rest of the circuit is immaterial.  Thus your Norton equivalent circuit is a current source of 2 amps (in parallel with an infinite resistance).

Comment: Brilliant, that was the confirmation I needed. I was finding very strange a situation like that. THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: How do you get infinite resistance between AB? It's clearly not.

Comment: @Chu, I'm still not clear if OP means R5 to be part of the source or part of the load. Presumably Barry assumed it's the load, not part of the source.

Comment: @The Photon The OP says the load is \$20\Omega\$ and across AB, so this circuit must be without load connected.